# Difference Between Matlab / Octave Solve and Numpy Solve

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, python, octave

I am trying to solve a linear system on Python for a problem which I ported from Octave. I have the following code for Octave

```
A=[    -1    -2    -4    -2    -3    -4;
       -2    -4    -4    -3    -4    -5;
       -1    -1    -1    -5    -5    -3;
       -2    -3    -5   100    -0    -0;
       -3    -4    -5    -0   100    -0;
       -4    -5    -3    -0    -0   100];

b = [3.9000;
     4.2000;
     4.3000;
     -9.0000;
     -9.0000;
     -9.0000];

A \ b
```

This gives

```
ans =

  -3.51998
   1.83663
  -0.66828
  -0.13871
  -0.15555
  -0.15902
```

On Python I have

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin

A = [[ -1.,  -2.,  -4.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.],
     [ -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.],
     [ -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -5.,  -5.,  -3.],
     [ -2.,  -3.,  -5., 100.,  -0.,  -0.],
     [ -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -0., 100.,  -0.],
     [ -4.,  -5.,  -3.,  -0.,  -0., 100.]]

b = [[ 3.9],
     [ 4.2],
     [ 4.3],
     [-9. ],
     [-9. ],
     [-9. ]]

A = np.array(A)
b = np.array(b)

print (lin.solve(A,b))
```

which gives

```
[[-7.70634652]
 [ 7.78318125]
 [-2.67111771]
 [-0.14418738]
 [-0.14341903]
 [-0.08922833]]
```

I am seeing different results.. I wonder why they are  different?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $(2,2)$ entries of $A$ disagree.

Comment: stupid mistake - thanks :|

Comment: @BBDynSys I often make the mistake of thinking the bug must be in the hard part of the code instead of in the easy part. Feel free to delete this question if you'd like, I don't mind.